# How do I combine tables with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have two tables of information: movies & history. My movies db has all the information about the movies. These are the rows in movies: id, title, photo, destination, description, rating, length, likes.

My history db has all the information about what movies the user has clicked on. These are the rows in history: id, user_id, movie_id.

**The Question**

I'm working on a feature called "My History." How do I show their history but also get the information from the movies in one SQL query?

For example:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY TABLE history WHERE user_id='$id'");
```

**I apologize if the answer seems simple. This is my first year working with programming in general. Thanks for any help give.**

Comment: Firstly, `ORDER BY` comes after a `WHERE` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html

Comment: Secondly, remove `TABLE` keyword and using `JOIN` keyword

Comment: Thirdly, read up on that http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Something like `SELECT h.*,m.title FROM history h JOIN movies m ON m.id = h.movie_id WHERE h.user_id=$id` isn't exactly what you want but it should get you started.

Comment: Fourthly, figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM movies m
INNER JOIN history h ON h.movie_id = m.id
WHERE h.user_id = $id
ORDER BY h.id  --not sure what you want to order by, but it goes here
```

That being said, you need to be aware of SQL Injection.  You should be using [prepared statements](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-php-using-prepared-statements) instead of just adding variables directly into your query.

Comment: and don't use evil "SELECT *"

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your query SQL.
I think you can try: (in Mysql)
`SELECT movies.* FROM history INNER JOIN movies ON history.movie_id = movies.id WHERE user_id = $id`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `JOIN` in MySQL.  You'll want to do something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies m 
JOIN history h ON m.id=h.movie_id 
AND h.user_id = $id
ORDER BY <column name>;
```

Basic concept behind this `JOIN` is you are taking the primary key from movies (id) and joining on its corresponding foreign key on history (movie_id).

It's also worth noting that `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` are all syntactic equivalents in MySQL.

Since you are just starting your first year in programming, I would highly recommend looking in to the documentation on `JOIN` and fully understanding it yourself, rather than copying and pasting an answer that works here.  It will be beneficial to you in the long run!  See the MySQL documentation on `JOIN` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).