# Using SQL JOIN function but choosing which columns are selected

Tags: php, mysql

Previously, I asked the following question: [How do I combine tables with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461565/how-do-i-combine-tables-with-sql)
I wanted to grab data from my movies db but order the information by my history db.

This is how I'm using the data:

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN history h ON h.movie_id = m.id WHERE h.user_id = $id3 ORDER BY h.id LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

Please don't worry about `$db2`, `$id3`, `$start` or `$per_page`. All of these variables are working properly...

I then use `$movie` with `$movie3`:

```
while($movie3 = mysqli_fetch_array($movie)) {
  echo $real_id = $movie3["id"];
}
```

**To be clear, everything is working properly with the data and ordering. However, `$real_id` is equal to the id from the history db, not the movies db. Can I have the best of both worlds? Keep what I have but change the content of `$real_id`?**

**UPDATE: How do I now select the proper id?**
This is my new query thanks to @Jay Blanchard

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT m.*,h.* FROM movies m INNER JOIN history h ON h.movie_id = m.id WHERE h.user_id = $id3 ORDER BY h.id LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

When I do this:

```
while($movie3 = mysqli_fetch_array($movie)) {
echo $movie3["id"];
}
```

**The id is still being retrieved by my `history db`. How do I now select the proper id?**

My guess would be something like this:

```
echo m.$movie3["id"];
```

Any feedback or ideas would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Don't worry! I was just making sure your code actually worked...

Comment: Not worried at all! I had just noticed that you haven't accepted many of the answers provided to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell the select the data to get -

```
SELECT m.id AS mid, h.id AS hid FROM movies m INNER JOIN history h...
```

Without specificity you will encounter column ambiguity which leads to heartache and depression. A comment in your other question pointed this out, but it bears repeating: select specific columns and do not use `*` *ever*.

---

**EDIT: (above query snippet modified)**

Now that the query is asking for specific columns and I have used good aliases for each column I can echo the columns easily:

```
echo $row['mid'];
```

Comment: To clarify for your specific problem: You'll want to `SELECT m.id, ...`. Then `$movie3["id"]` will be filled with the ID you're looking for.

Comment: Great answer! How do I now select the proper id? Please see my update in the actual question for more details...